# Can the word "diplomacy" be used to refer to a particular form of diplomacy or diplomatic strategy?

Tags: word-usage

I'm thinking of a usage for "diplomacy" such as:

> "Unlike his predecessor's isolationist policies, Schultz's *diplomacy* favored providing aid unconditionally to neighbors in the region on the premise that they would be more likely to support the country's interests should the need arise.

I think this sounds more eloquent than "Schultz's style of diplomacy" or "Schultz's diplomatic policy" but I haven't seen this usage before and it sounds a bit foreign. We do this with other words, e.g. "government of the people, by the people, and for the people" or "a whole different ballgame" or "we wanted to breed a sweeter apple." Perhaps it's a more idiomatic convention and not technically correct grammar?

Comment: One definition of *diplomacy* is *The profession, activity, or skill of managing international relations...* So your example could be read as *specific acts* of diplomacy. This could be in contrast to "X's *style of diplomacy* was often criticized, but few argued with its success."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly acceptable. A genitive NP marking a specific style of diplomacy can readily be found in high quality English, therefore it's grammatical.

> Trump's diplomacy is hardly the only part of his presidency shaped
> by his experiences with golf courses. (Washington Post, 2017)
>
> The two distinctive contributions of the Conservative Party's
> diplomacy in this century have been at the time of Suez when we
> committed aggression ourselves, and at Munich where we supported it in
> another. (British House of Commons, 1960)
>
> Even those allies who supported the United States complained privately
> about the paucity of consultation and the ineffectiveness of the
> administration's diplomacy. (Foreign Affairs, 2003)